# Making a Chrome extension not work on certain pages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am creating an extension and I need to know how to make a filter, so that it is not activated on certain pages (which the user chooses). I don't know much about web development, so don't think that your solution is 'so easy that it mustn't work'.

Answer (score 1):

You can [programatically inject javascript](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/content_scripts.html#pi) into pages:

```
//in background.html
var allowedUrlList = ["http://..."];
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if(changeInfo.status == "complete") {
        if(allowedUrlList.indexOf(tab.url) != -1) {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: "content_script.js"});
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Good answer.  You might elaborate on things like getting the `allowedUrlList` from `localStorage` as the asker might not have enough context to work with just this snippet...

Comment: I think that I am OK with this. I have adapted it for what I want and have used the localStorage. Now I just need to make an options page.